Entity Framework Core not binding primary key
I'm using Entity Framework Core in a .NET Core application and I am running into some weird issues. When I try to retrieve a previously saved object, the primary key of the object is null, even though it is set in the database.
Example / code:
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserData> UserDatas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        CreateRelationships(modelBuilder);
        CreateIndexs(modelBuilder);
    }

    private void CreateRelationships(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne(e => e.UserData)
            .WithOne(e => e.User)
            .HasForeignKey<UserData>(e => e.UserID)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Session)
            .WithOne(e => e.User)
            .HasForeignKey<Session>(e => e.UserID)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Navigation(u => u.Session)
            .AutoInclude();

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Navigation(u => u.UserData)
            .AutoInclude();
    }

    public bool GetUserByCondition(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<User, bool>> predicate, out User? user)
    {
        user = Users.FirstOrDefault(predicate);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        Log.LogToDB($"UserData is null: {user.UserData == null}");
        Log.LogToDB($"Session is null: {user.Session == null}");
        Log.LogToDB($"User ID: {user.UserID}");

        // TODO: Figure out why eager loading isn't working
        Entry(user).Reference(u => u.Session).Load();
        Log.LogToDB($"Session ID: {user.Session.SessionID}");

        Entry(user).Reference(u => u.UserData).Load();
        Log.LogToDB($"UserData ID: {user.UserData.UserDataID}");

        // for some reason the context will think all of these are being added after updating them and calling .SaveChanges(). Manually attach them to fix this
        Attach(user);
        Attach(user.Session);

        // Exception throwing because user.UserData.UserDataID = 0 / is unset
        Attach(user.UserData);

        return true;
    }
}

public class User : IUser
{
     [Key]
     public long UserID { get; set; }
     public UserData UserData { get; set; }
     public Session Session { get; set; }

     protected User() { }

     public User(Context db)
     {
         UserData ud = new UserData(this);
         UserData = ud;
         db.UserDatas.Add(ud);
     }
}

public class Session : ISession
{
    [Key]
    public long SessionID { get; set; }
    public long UserID { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    protected Session() { }

    static public Session CreateSessionForUser(User user, out string token)
    {
       Session session = new Session()
       {
            UserID = user.UserID,
            User = user,
       };

       return session;
    }
}

static public class SessionHelper
{
     static public void CreateNewSessionForUser(Context db, User user)
     {
         Session newSession = Session.CreateSessionForUser(user, out token);

         db.Sessions.Add(newSession);
         db.SaveChanges();
     }
}

public class UserData : IUserData 
{
     [Key]
     public long UserDataID { get; set; }
     public long UserID { get; set; }
     public User User { get; set; }
}

The weird behavior is happening in GetUserByCondition. The first log checking if user.UserData == null will print false, but the second log checking user.Session == null will print true despite both navigations being specified as AutoInclude in OnModelCreating.
After manually loading the Session via
Entry(user).Reference(u => u.Session).Load();

printing user.Session.SessionID will print the correct id. Trying to do the same thing with UserData, however, will print null or 0 depending on if I switch UserDataID to nullable or not. I have confirmed that all 3 objects are in the database and that all foreign keys / relationships are set up.



Any help into why Entity Framework Core is failing to retrieve the primary key on UserDatas would be appreciated

Inspect the connection string at runtime with a breakpoint using var connectionString = Database.GetConnectionString(); inside your GetUserByCondition method. My first suspicion if UserData is eager loading while Session is not, then it may be hitting a different database than you expect. For one-to-one relationships where stuff hangs off users I wouldn't expose DbSets for those related entities, just access them through the User and it's navigation properties. EF will wire up and insert them properly without the extra steps of adding to a DbSet.

@StevePy I've been stuck on this for so long. Removing the DbSets for the one-to-one relationships fixed it and now everything works as expected. Thank you! Any idea why this was causing such strange behavior? Was this expected / documented behavior?

Honestly not sure, normally having the DbSets and adding the items wouldn't be a problem, it's just an unnecessary step, but something in the way you might be adding/associating the items may be confusing EF. Hard to say, and why it would seem to affect one relationship and not the other when as far as the relationships are concerned they look the same. The factory method approach is different for both of them, so that may be a factor in how they might be wired when created and pulled from a tracking cache vs. read from the DB.

You could use Include , because AutoInclude might not always guarantee immediate loading. EF Core might still defer loading UserData until it's explicitly accessed (lazy loading). Another point is, when you call FirstOrDefault on Users, EF Core might not automatically track the retrieved User object. If UserData wasn't included in the initial query, it might remain untracked even though the foreign key (UserID) is set.

What is the UserData constructor doing? You’ve omitted it from your example

I see you changed your approach but since I found it, will share it!
First of all, I saw that your ctor is strange, but after some debugging found that when EF Core tries to load your object from the DB it loads only the UserData object base on your code. This is why you see your object in the DB but not loaded by EF Core!
public User(Context db)
     {
         UserData ud = new UserData(this);
         UserData = ud;
         db.UserDatas.Add(ud);
     }

